# Can "Shared with you" on Google Drive be filtered into folders?

Tags: google-drive

Specifically, I would like to know if there is any way, either through a script or through the API so that files shared with me from another user are automatically placed into a folder.  The sorting I'm looking for would sort by the author (or owner) of the file, but filtering by title would work as well.